# How to turn on developer mode on chromeOS

Tags: permissions, chrome-os

I'm trying to enable developer mode on chromeOS. I know the <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Refresh</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> but when I do that my Chromebook says "Chromebook last booted in developer mode etc." then logs in without it.

How do I get past this?